# How to append dictionary in array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have one array of dictionary and I am trying to do is get first object from array and append in my secondArray. Dictionary is `[String: AnyObject]` and array is of `String`. Here is my code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
let myDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = dataArray[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]
selectedArray.append(myDictionary)
```

But I am getting error :

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to expected argument type 'String'.

How can I add dictionary in array?

Comment: Maybe you have typo in the error citation... Please correct

Comment: How you declared `selectedArray`? Try to declare it as:- `var selectedArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your array of dictionary type `[[String: AnyObject]]` like this, than append `Dictionary` inside that array.

```
var selectedArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()
let myDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = dataArray[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]
selectedArray.append(myDictionary)
```

or if you want the array of string `[String]` then you need to append that specific `String` from that dictionary like this.

```
var selectedArray = [String]()
let myDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = dataArray[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]
if let str = myDictionary["Key"] as? String {
    selectedArray.append(str)
}
```